# Отправка формы обратной связи на несколько емеил

Tags: php, email

Использую данную библиотеку для отправки данных из форм обратной связи на эмеил
https://github.com/agragregra/uniMail
Появилась потребность отправки данных сразу на несколько почт.
Подскажите, как это можно реализовать

Comment: Извините, но не могу понять зачем вы пошли более сложным путем, если можно форму передать через ajax, где вы на php обработаете ее и через стандартную функцию mail() отправить почту(ссылка:
     http://www.php.su/mail()
), где указать в параметре $to массив получателей.
Без подключения сторонних библиотек и плагинов

Comment: К тому же в самом исходнике этой библиотеки используют ту же стандартную функцию mail()

Comment: Не разбираюсь в php, поэтому использую данную библиотеку, потому что в ней можно указывать тему письма и адрес, не трогая при этом php обработчик, чтоб ничего там не сломать

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, без ковыряния исходного кода самого скрипта реализовать не получится. Прямо в файле mail.php на 51 строке объявить массив с нужными адресами, а потом через цикл отправлять письма.

```
$emails=array("some@example.com","some2@example.com","some3@example.com");
foreach($emails as $email){
  mail($email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers);
  unset($email);
}
```

Лучше почитайте про phpMailer